# nested list css problems

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having trouble nesting a list in the following. The nested list isn't appearing on the page. I assume its something to do with my JS hiding it. Can anyone see what the problem may be - it's driving me mad!

```
<ul class="question">  
     <li><a href="#">QUESTION goes here</a>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#">ANSWER goes here></a>
      </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">QUESTION 2 goes here</a>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#">ANSWER 2 goes here>
         <li>
         <ul>
            <li>nested list item 1</li>
            <li>nested list item 2</li>
            <li>nested list item 3</li>
         </ul>
         </li></a>
      </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

My JS:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#question > li > a').click(function(){

if (!$(this).hasClass('active')){
$('#question li ul').slideUp();
$(this).next().slideToggle();
$('#question li a').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
}
else{
$('#question li ul').slideUp();
$('#question li a').removeClass('active');
}
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: should "question" be a 'class' or 'id'?

Comment: [This works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/8kTdk/1/). Show us your CSS or the live page.

Comment: You have a `li` nested in another `li` at the `ANSWER 2 goes here`. By specification, a `li` element can go only inside a `ul` element, so the browser is doing some magic behind the scenes(closing and opening tags for you). Remove that inner `li` element

Comment: Thanks for your comments, all sorted now - see comment below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:
http://jsfiddle.net/eAJjs/

```
$('#question > li > a').click(function () {

    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $('#question>li>ul').slideUp();
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
        $('#question>li>a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    } else {
        $('#question>li>ul').slideUp();
        $('#question>li>a').removeClass('active');
    }
});


<ul id="question">
    <li><a href="#">QUESTION goes here</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">ANSWER goes here></a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">QUESTION 2 goes here</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">ANSWER 2 goes here>
         <li>
             <ul>
                <li>nested list item 1</li>
                <li>nested list item 2</li>
                <li>nested list item 3</li>
             </ul>
         </li></a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great - It was my CSS that was causing the problems! I had a display:none on my 2nd <li>!! Sometimes you can't see for looking! Thanks for your help.